# Time as y- axis labels in ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time

I'm having a hard time plotting time up the Y axis on a ggplot2 box plot.

Any ideas how I can present my y-axis as time?

Currently, my Y axis is numeric, with date labels applied to the series.

I would prefer to show time (HH:MM) on the Y-axis, instead of showing all of the data labels

My data:

```
structure(list(Date = structure(c(17511, 17512, 17513, 17514, 17515), class = "Date"), 
T.min = c(1513584134, 1513580301, 1513582918, 1513583058, 1513584465), 
T.mean = c(1513585975.14286, 1513584408.14286, 1513584580.57143, 1513583202.2, 1513585681), 
T.max = c(1513587691, 1513587419, 1513585508, 1513583516, 1513587100), 
min_labels = c("08:02", "06:58", "07:41", "07:44", "08:07"), 
mean_labels = c("08:32", "08:06", "08:09", "07:46", "08:28"), 
max_labels = c("09:01", "08:56", "08:25", "07:51", "08:51")), .Names = c("Date", "T.min", "T.mean", "T.max", "min_labels", "mean_labels", "max_labels"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")
```

My plot (the y axis and plotted values are in POSIXct format):

```
#Library
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

#Plot
theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = T.min, lower = T.min, middle = T.mean, upper = T.max, ymax = T.max), 
           stat = "identity", fill = "antiquewhite", color = "black") + 
  geom_line(aes(x=Date, y=T.mean),color='firebrick2', size=3, show.legend = FALSE) +
  xlab('Shift Start Date') + 
  ylab('Time') +
  coord_cartesian( ylim =c(Y.min, Y.max) ) + 
  scale_x_date(date_labels =  "%d-%b", breaks = pretty_breaks(5)) + 
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15), axis.title=element_text(size=15,face="bold")) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + 
  theme(axis.text.y = element_blank()) + 
  geom_text(aes(x=Date, y = T.min, label = min_labels), size=5, vjust=1.5, check_overlap=TRUE) + 
  geom_text(aes(x=Date, y = T.mean, label = mean_labels), size=5, vjust=-0.5, check_overlap=TRUE) + 
  geom_text(aes(x=Date, y = T.max, label = max_labels), size=5, vjust=-1.5, check_overlap=TRUE) + 
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15), axis.title=element_text(size=15,face="bold")) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

[image: Current plot output]

What I'm aiming for (labels added in MS Paint and don't match up well with the data, but you can see what I'm wanting) :-)
[image: What I'm aiming for]

Comment: how should the y-axis look like?

Comment: Can you please explain: "hide the Y-axis labels.... show the y axis labels and hide the min and max data labels"

Comment: Thanks for the questions, I've edited the post to be clearer. Many thanks!

Comment: Which is the unit in `T.mean` are seconds or a specific hour?

Comment: Hi, the numeric values are POSIXct, so the units are seconds. The output format I would like to achieve is hours and minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my attempt. Given `1513584000` indicates `2017-12-18 08:00:00 GMT`, I found the values for every 30 min between 06:00 and 10:00 for the 18th of December, 2017. The numbers are stored in `nums`.

```
nums <- seq(from = 1513584000 - 7200, to = 1513584000 + 7200, length.out = 9)

[1] 1513576800 1513578600 1513580400 1513582200 1513584000 1513585800 1513587600 1513589400
[9] 1513591200
```

Then, I converted `nums` to a date object and extracted hour and minute using `format()`. This allows me to have new labels for y-axis. They are stored in `labels`.

```
labels <- as.POSIXct(nums, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT") %>%
          format("%H:%M")

# [1] "06:00" "06:30" "07:00" "07:30" "08:00" "08:30" "09:00" "09:30" "10:00"
```

I changed the y scale using `scale_y_continuous()`. I set the `limits` argument with the min and max values in `nums`.

```
g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Date)) + 
     geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = T.min, lower = T.min, middle = T.mean, upper = T.max, ymax = T.max), 
                  stat = "identity", fill = "antiquewhite", color = "black") + 
     geom_line(aes(x=Date, y=T.mean),color='firebrick2', size=3, show.legend = FALSE) +
     xlab('Shift Start Date') + 
     ylab('Time') +
     ylim(c(min(df$T.min)-1800, max(df$T.max)+ 1800)) +
     scale_x_date(date_labels =  "%d-%b", breaks = pretty_breaks(5)) + 
     theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15), axis.title=element_text(size=15,face="bold")) + 
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +  
     geom_text(aes(x=Date, y = T.min, label = min_labels), size=5, vjust=1.5, check_overlap=TRUE) + 
     geom_text(aes(x=Date, y = T.mean, label = mean_labels), size=5, vjust=-0.5, check_overlap=TRUE) + 
     geom_text(aes(x=Date, y = T.max, label = max_labels), size=5, vjust=-1.5, check_overlap=TRUE) + 
     theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15), axis.title=element_text(size=15,face="bold")) + 
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) +
     scale_y_continuous(breaks = nums, labels = labels, limits = c(nums[1], nums[length(nums)]))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for your help, that is excellent!  I'm new to ggplot2 and this really helps.

Comment: @Jernau I haven't done this task before, so this was a good learning opportunity for me as well. There may be a better way to move around. But this approach works. If your case is done, please click the green tick next to the up/down vote triangles and close your inquiry.

Comment: The key for me here was setting the y axis as continuous and specifying the 'breaks', 'labels' and 'limits'. I'll post my final code below.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Jazzurro. The approach suggested, with a small tweak, allowed the axis to be modified easily for re-use in further plots

The final output (extra data labels could now be hidden)
[image: The Final Output]

The 'final' code I settled on looks like this:

```
#Define Y-axis range (use half hour steps) in both POSIXct and numeric forms
Y.minT <- as.POSIXct("06:00:00" , format = "%H:%M:%S")
Y.maxT <- as.POSIXct("12:00:00" , format = "%H:%M:%S")
Y.min <- as.numeric(Y.minT)
Y.max <- as.numeric(Y.maxT)

#Create the axis breaks
nums <- seq(from = Y.min, to = Y.max, length.out = 1+abs(2 * difftime(Y.maxT, Y.minT)[[1]]))

#Create a vector of date labels
labels <- as.POSIXct(nums, origin = "1970-01-01", tz = "GMT") %>% format("%H:%M")

#Changed the y-axis as suggested, specifying 'breaks', 'labels' and 'limits'
#  scale_y_continuous(breaks = nums, labels = labels, limits = c(Y.min, Y.max))

#Plot
theme_set(theme_bw())
ggplot(df, aes(x = Date)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(ymin = T.min, lower = T.min, middle = T.mean, upper = T.max, ymax = T.max), 
           stat = "identity", fill = "antiquewhite", color = "black") + 
  geom_line(aes(x=Date, y=T.mean),color='firebrick2', size=3, show.legend = FALSE) +
  xlab('Date') + 
  ylab('Time') +
  scale_x_date(date_labels =  "%d-%b", breaks = pretty_breaks(5)) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = nums, labels = labels, limits = c(Y.min, Y.max)) +
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15), axis.title=element_text(size=15,face="bold")) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + 
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=15), axis.title=element_text(size=15,face="bold")) + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1)) + 
  #geom_text(aes(x = Date, y = T.min, label = min_labels), size=5, vjust=1.5, check_overlap=TRUE) + 
  #geom_text(aes(x=Date, y = T.max, label = max_labels), size=5, vjust=-1.5, check_overlap=TRUE) +
  geom_text(aes(x=Date, y = T.mean, label = mean_labels), size=5, vjust=-0.5, check_overlap=TRUE)
```

Comment: Glad to see you achieved your goal. :)